# Move a file to a directory that is within another directory and rename it in one command line?

Tags: linux

So, we have a parent_dir and it contains a child_dir and a file1. How can I move a file1 to a child_dir and rename it as file2? let's assume my pwd is /var

Comment: What did you try? Where did you got stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can just move a file from one dest. to another (it changes its name):

```
mv /parent_dir/file1 /parent_dir/child_dir/file2
```

Comment: Thanks! Well actually I tried this command several times but now when I typed my pwd before the new path it actually worked.